# Tailwind CSS IntelliSense not working on my VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I recently start using tailwind CSS in my react app. Tailwind work when I use its class in elements. But Intellisense plugins doesn't suggest classes when I start typing.
I see other people have same problem and saw the solution others explain but after all I can't fix this.

Alos it doesn't work on html files to when I create a .html file

I used tilwind installation document on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app to install tailwind.

---

I play around with some setting and configuration that others said like:

- I added these lines to the setting.json file [setting.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py86E.png)

> "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
> "javascriptreact": "html",
> "typescriptreact": "html",
> "plaintext": "html"
> },

> "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,

> "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,

- And also use "npx tailwindcss-cli@latest init" command to create tailwind.config.js file
  [tailwind.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Db7i.png)

But after all it still doesn't work and I don't know what else I should do.
If someone could give me a hand with this problem. Thanks

Comment: One of the problem is opening a folder/select folder that doesn't contain tailwind.config.js. e.g. src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to vscode setting.json:

`"editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": true }`

That worked for me as mine seemed to have issues with auto suggestions while typing in strings.